# iOS nested viewcontrollers and interface builder

Tags: ios, interface-builder, viewcontroller

I'm very new to iOS development and i'm trying to get my head around viewControllers and how they're used with storyboards. I've read a lot of the official documentation on viewControllers, Objective-C and i've played around with xCode to familiarise myself with it.

I'm trying to create the following:

Main Window
   - My starting view should contain three "frames" (i'm trying not to use iOS terminology as I don't want to confuse things)

- Frame 1) A rectangular area stretching across the screen containing three buttons. Each button when pressed causes frame 2 below to change between different views. This frame kind of acts like a tab view controller but with the tabs at the top and the view being changed in frame 2.
- Frame 2) Contains two columns of scrollable table items. When an item in the first column is selected, it causes the contents in the second column to change.
- Frame 3) A simple scrolling text label.

My thinking was that I could achieve the above as follows:

InitialViewController
    Frame 1) One nested/embedded containerViewController containing 3 buttons
    Frame 2) Two embedded tableViewControllers. I was thinking that TVC 1 could pass the cell selected action up to the mainViewController (via delegation) which would then instruct TVC 2 to change it's contents.
    Frame 3) A scrollable view

I'm trying to create the above in a storyboard and i'm stuck with frame 2, I've created Frame 1 (a containerViewController containing 3 buttons) but when I try to drag a tableViewController onto my main view it's not letting me. Dragging it onto the canvas is fine, it just wont let me drag it onto the main view.

Have I misunderstood how to use viewControllers (and therefore my planned design is wrong) or is it something i'm not doing correctly in the xcode interface designer?

Any help really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the correct terminology, then you probably won't be thinking about your structure correctly. Frame 1, for instance, should be a UIView containing three buttons, not an embedded controller. "Frame 2", could be 2 embedded table view controllers, but I think a 2 component UIPickerView might be more appropriate. As for embedding controllers in another controller's view in the storyboard, you do that by dragging in a container view, and that will give you a new controller automatically.

I think you have misunderstood view controllers. A view controller can have multiple subviews (buttons, a picker view, a label) that it can host, you don't necessarily need to have multiple view controllers to do what you're trying.

Comment: thanks rdelmar. regarding "Frame 2" - i'll take a look into the UIPickerView. Can you explain when an embedded view controller would be used in preference to a embedded view (or view hierarchy) please?

Comment: @Wazzag, it's hard to answer that question in the abstract. Mainly, it depends what's going on in that embedded view and how it's related to what the main controller is doing.

Comment: thanks for your help. I've had a look at the UIPickerView and I think the tableView is more suitable. I now have two questions - 1) Do I need a tableViewController or can I just use a tableView in my main UIView? 2) How do I create the UITableView (+controller?) in the storyboard? I've tried  but I received an exception: "reason: '... nib but didn't get a UITableView.'" What I did was: dragged a ContainerView into my scene then changed class of the controller it created to a class that's a sub-class of UITableViewController.

Comment: After googling the exception it seems that the following is the answer: If you have a UITableViewController and your root element is not a UITableView, you should make your controller extend UIViewController (not UITableViewController) and implement the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource interfaces. (http://www.tonyzampogna.com/2011/10/30/uncaught-exception-nsinternalinconsistencyexception-reason-uitableviewcontroller-loadview-loaded-the-some-id-nib-but-didnt-get-a-uitableview/)